# recursive function that calls recursion inside for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a class for a Street which is just a line with a beginning point and an end point, inside this same class I have a function called checkIntersections which :

- checks if this Street intersects with a given Street and its children which are also of type Street.
- returns true at the first found intersection
- returns false or undefined if no recursive intersections were found

I decided to make checkIntersections a recursive function but I think I'm going about it wrong because nested intersections between streets are not being detected.

```
  checkIntersections(street){

if(intersects(this.beginning, this.end, street.beginning, street.end)){
  return true;
}
else{
  for(var i = 0 , count = street.children.length ; i < count ; i++){
    this.checkIntersections(street.children[i]);  
  }
}
```

}

Is there anything that I should be attentive to while making recursive calls inside a for loop in javascript ? The output of the function is always undefined.

Comment: I think all `this.checkIntersections(street.children[i])` values must be evaluated and returned instead of returning the result of the first index.

Comment: I was under the impression that my code did what you just described. Would you give me a pointer as to what I've missed ? Thanks

Comment: when you use the `return` statement the rest of the iterations will not happen, so you have to return after lopping everything

Comment: if any of the children intersect, does that mean the parent street intersects? Or should all children intersect?

Comment: I've updated my question giving more details on this, the function should
returns true at the first found intersection, and return false or undefined if no recursive intersections were found. Following your advice I've also updated the code to not use the return statement inside the for loop. But now all I get are undefined outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not using the value returned from the recursive call -- it just ignores it and just continues with the next recursive call. Instead it should detect a success from a recursive call and then exit immediately, returning that success to its own caller.

```
checkIntersections(street) {
    if (intersects(this.beginning, this.end, street.beginning, street.end)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        for (let child of street.children) { // Use modern for..of loop
            let success = this.checkIntersections(child);
            if (success) return true; // bubble up the happy result!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I think it makes sense now, I was expecting the 'return true' in my if statement to return true recursively, but I realize now that my function this.checkIntersections(child) returned 'true' and not 'return true' Thanks again for helping it works perfectly

Comment: Wouldn't something like `... else {return street.children.some(child => this .checkIntersection (child))}` (untested) be both simpler and more explicit?

Comment: @Scott, sure, but this answer focuses on the problem in the Asker's code, so I kept the explicit loop.

Comment: Yes of course.  I wasn't thinking straight.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like

```js
checkIntersections(street) {
  if (intersects(this.beginning, this.end, street.beginning, street.end)) {
    return true;
  } else if (street.children.length) {
    return street.children.some( checkIntersections );
  }
  return false;
}
```

- you need to `return` the recursive call to `checkIntersections`
- it would be better to use `.some` for the `children` as it will do a early exit
- you need to provide a default return in case there are no children and the current intersection failed.